# Why can't we invoke ReactDOM or React directly in the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I'm new to React and I'm still trying to wrap my head around how it works.

I understand that in our React code before "compiling" we can use `React.createElement` and `ReactDOM.render` to do all sorts of stuff but after the code is compiled and run on the client, suppose I wanted to dynamically create a new DOM node with one of my components.

**Adding some code for further explanation**

This is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello World!
            </div>
        )
    }

}

ReactDOM.render(
    //React Element,
    <HelloWorld />,
    //where to render the Element to
    document.getElementById('hello')
)
```

This works fine. However when I try dynamically adding the component "live" via the devtools console and type `React.createElement`,  I get:

`React is not defined`

The same with ReactDOM. Are they not available via the console? There's probably something missing in my understanding and I'm thinking about this wrong but how exactly is `React` and `ReactDOM` not defined if my index.js was able to invoke `ReactDOM.render`?
Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're using create-react-app? Because you can absolutely include the two React scripts directly and call ReactDOM anywhere you like. Just not in a compiled CRA, because the modules you're writing are put together into a single isolated script. However it should be pointed out that you are not really supposed to create elements on the fly like that; what you do in react for instance is add a new object to a state array; this will rerun your render function and automatically add a new element (since you wrote the render function accordingly)

Comment: Here's an example of newly created DOM nodes: https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-meadow-ebgov?file=/src/App.js

Comment: When I clicked the "Console" tab at the bottom-left of the "Browser" panel in your link and tried to type out React or ReactDOM it still gave me "is not defined".
I think you're trying to explain that ReactDOM works in the React code which it does as well in my React code: I see the HelloWorld component rendered. I am trying to understand why I can't do that "on the fly" directly from the browser.

Comment: I didn't use create-react-app - I'm assuming it's a scaffolding command to create a react app? Just added everything (webpack, babel, loaders and webpack-dev-server) from scratch following a basic tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but you're also using webpack so React/ReactDOM are again not visible to the console. My codesandbox example was pointing out that what you're trying to do is not necessary anyway. Again: webpack takes ES6 modules that use import and export and compiles them into a single script, one that is isolated from the common namespace. You cannot access anything inside from the console because it's all wrapped in a big function. However you needn't and you shouldn't.

Comment: Right I see.. I'm evaluating React for a multi page application and wanting to stay away from the SPA architecture. Trying to understand how to use React minimally to declare and define components but wanting to "manage" them and everything else out of React including having a page with several "root" React components instead of one big main "App" root component. That's why I tried going down this path.

Comment: There's [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) but not sure if that's useful to you? There's also [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start) which uses SEO friendly URLs

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG I will take a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

React and ReactDOM can be used in the console if:

1. You export, what you need in the global scope, from webpack's entry point. For example:

   `export {React, ReactDOM, LeaveStats }`
2. The bundle generated from webpack is included in the HTML page via a non-module script
3. Webpack is configured to output a "library" like so:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app/LeaveStats.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        library: 'ReactApp' // <-- this will allow us access to whatever is exported in ./app/LeaveStats.js
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
        ]
    },
    mode: 'development'
}
```

You can then have access to `React`, `ReactDOM` and `LeaveStats` from the global scope e.g.:

```
ReactApp.ReactDOM.render(
    ReactApp.React.createElement(ReactApp.LeaveStats), 
    document.getElementById("mydiv")
)
```

Not that I would really use this, but kind of helped my understand a few things along the way reaching to this point.

Comment: FYI: Rollup has a different configuration for exposing exported items in their bundle. For one, you cannot use the "es" format (use "umd" instead) because otherwise you'd need to include the bundle as a "module" so then won't be available outside. Then you need to specify an output name via which you can have access.